# How do I upload an image to Azure Blob Storage with NextJS API?

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-blob-storage, blob, image-upload

I have a React component that sends user's profile image to a proxy nextjs api (want to keep the proxy API so Azure secrets aren't visible in browser network tab).

Here's the front-end react code:

```
 const [image, setImage] = useState({ preview: '', raw: '' })

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    setImage({
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      raw: e.target.files[0]
    })
  }

     // Form the request for sending picture to server.
     const picFile = new FormData()
     picFile.append("image", image.raw)
     const picOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      body: picFile,
    }

const picResponse = await fetch(profilePicEndpoint, picOptions)
return (
<input accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" type="file" id="image-upload" style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={handleImageChange} />
)
```

And here's what the proxy (NextJS) api send to Azure Blob Storage via the SAS token

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const body = req.body
    //handle sending profile pic to azure blob storage
    const blobEndpoint = 'https://STORAGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/MyContainerhere/Testfile.png?BunchofCredentialsHere'
    const blobOptions = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
      },
      body: req.body,
    }
    const blobResponse = await fetch(blobEndpoint, blobOptions)
    // console.log(blobResponse)

    // Sends a HTTP success code
    res.status(200).json({ message: ` Submission successful. Please give 24 hours for updates to be reflected on this page.` })
  }
```

It ends up transforming the png to a bunch of random characters (I'm assuming this is binary code of the file?) to the nextjs api, which ends up sending the same thing to the azure blob storage. I just want the file to upload to the nextjs api, then to azure blob storage as a png/jpeg/whatever image type.

Thanks for any help/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below next.js code to upload an image as a blob to my storage account.

**Code:**

**upload.js**:

```js
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { base64Image } = req.body;

      const storageAccount = '<account-name>';
      const containerName = 'container-name>';
      const accessKey = '<access-key>';
      const connectionString = `<connect-string>`;

      const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
      const filename = `${Date.now()}.png`;
      const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Image, 'base64');
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);
      await blockBlobClient.uploadData(imageBuffer, { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/png' } });

      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error occured' });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: 'not allowed' });
  }
}
```

**ImageUploader.js**:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ImageUploader() {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const handleImageUpload = async () => {
    if (selectedImage) {
      try {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
        reader.onloadend = async () => {
          const base64Image = reader.result.split(',')[1];

          await axios.post('/api/upload', { base64Image });
        };
      } catch (error) {
      }
    }
  };

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedImage(file);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageChange} />
      <button onClick={handleImageUpload}>Upload Image to storage account</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**index.js:**

```html
import ImageUploader from '../components/ImageUploader';  
  
export default function Home() {  
return (  
<div>   
<h1>Image Upload using Next-js</h1>  
<ImageUploader />  
</div>  
);  
}
```

My project structure looks like below,

[image]

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above **URL**, I got the output in the browser as below,

[image]

choose **an image file** and click on **upload image** button like below,

[image]

***Then, the image uploaded successfully to the storage account as below,***

[image]

Comment: After 3 days of messing with the multer package, multi-form, octet-stream content types; this route worked flawlessly. Thank you so much, worked like a charm!

Comment: @Chance You are welcome, if you have any doubts feel free to ask.