# How can I upload a file input to azure blob in nextjs?

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-blob-storage

I am learning this tutorial on youtube:https://youtu.be/dTFXufTgfOE. This is the github:https://github.com/dejwid/ecommerce-admin

In upload.js the original tutorial uses AWS and I want to use Azure and it is called in productForm.js, so I got this code from ChatGPT for upload.js:

Here is productForm.js:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";
import Spinner from "@/components/Spinner";
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";

export default function ProductForm({
  _id,
  title: existingTitle,
  description: existingDescription,
  price: existingPrice,
  images: existingImages,
  category: assignedCategory,
  properties: assignedProperties,
})
```

I never used Azure or AWS before, so please excuse me as I don't understand anything yet and I want to learn. Please tell me what I need to do to make a blob storage and how can I use it to upload the images to it.

Comment: Check my solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419808/how-do-i-upload-an-image-to-azure-blob-storage-with-nextjs-api/76455583#76455583) to upload images as a blob to storage account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upload an image to Azure Blob Storage with NextJS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419808/how-do-i-upload-an-image-to-azure-blob-storage-with-nextjs-api)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419808/how-do-i-upload-an-image-to-azure-blob-storage-with-nextjs-api/76455583#76455583), Refer the steps below.

Firstly, I created a storage account and a container in the Azure portal as below,

[image]

I tried the below **next js** code to upload images to my storage account container.

**Code:**

**src/components/ImageUploader.js** :

> ```js
> import { useState } from 'react';
> import axios from 'axios';
>
> export default function ImageUploader() {   const [selectedImage,
> setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
>
>   const handleImageUpload = async () => {
>     if (selectedImage) {
>       try {
>         const reader = new FileReader();
>         reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
>         reader.onloadend = async () => {
>           const base64Image = reader.result.split(',')[1];
>
>           await axios.post('/api/upload', { base64Image });
>         };
>       } catch (error) {
>       }
>     }   };
>
>   const handleImageChange = (event) => {
>     const file = event.target.files[0];
>     setSelectedImage(file);   };
>
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageChange} />
>       <button onClick={handleImageUpload}>Upload Image to storage account</button>
>     </div>   ); }
> ```

Go to your **storage account**> **Access keys**> **Key** and **Connection string**. Copy the key and connection string and use them in the below code,

[image]

**src/pages/api/upload.js** :

> ```js
> import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';
>
> export default async function handler(req, res) {   if (req.method ===
> 'POST') {
>     try {
>       const { base64Image } = req.body; 
>
>       const storageAccount = '<storage_name>';
>       const containerName = '<container_name>';
>       const accessKey = '<storage_key>';
>       const connectionString = `<storage_connec_string>>`;
>
>       const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
>
>       const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
>       const filename = `${Date.now()}.png`;
>       const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Image, 'base64');
>       const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);
>       await blockBlobClient.uploadData(imageBuffer, { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/png' } });
>
>       res.status(200).json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' });
>     } catch (error) {
>       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error occured' });
>     }   } else {
>     res.status(405).json({ error: 'not allowed' });   } }
> ```

**src/pages/index.js** :

> ```js
> import ImageUploader from '../components/ImageUploader';
>
> export default function Home() {   return (
>     <div>
>      
>
>  <h1>Image Upload using Next-js</h1>
>       <ImageUploader />
>     </div>   ); }
> ```

package.json:

> ```json
>  {  
>   "name": "my-app",   
>  "version": "0.1.0",  
>   "private": true,
> "scripts": {
>     "dev": "next dev",
>     "build": "next build",
>     "start": "next start",
>     "lint": "next lint"   },  
>      "dependencies": {
>     "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.14.0",
>     "axios": "^1.4.0",
>     "next": "13.4.5",
>     "react": "18.2.0",
>     "react-dom": "18.2.0"   
>     } }
> ```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above output **URL**, I got the below in the browser. I click on **Choose File** to select a **png Image** file that I want to upload and click on **Upload Imgae to storage account**.

[image]

***The image file as a blob was uploaded successfully to my storage account container in Azure Portal as below,***

[image]

Comment: Please don't repeat answers, instead flag or vote to close as duplicate.